# How to set array key in the query

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

Expected result:
I'm trying to insert a key to includes same department data as below

```
"data": {
        "Department A": {
            "code": "9781848574472",
            "department": "Department A",
            "total_quantity": 198,
            "total_price": "0.00"
        },
        {
            "code": "9781848574649",
            "department": "Department A",
            "total_quantity": 8,
            "total_price": "0.00"
        },
        "Department C": {
            "code": "ABC001",
             "department": "Department C",
            "total_quantity": 1,
            "total_price": "100.00"
        }
    },
```

Code

```
 Sale_item::where('tags.type', 'Department')       
                                    ->selectRaw('code, 'department', tags.name AS department, sum(qty) as total_quantity, sum(total) as total_price')
                                    ->get()
                                    ->keyBy('department');
```

After added keyBy
I have the query results below.

```
"data": {
        "Department A": {
            "code": "9781848574472",
            "department": "Department A",
            "total_quantity": 198,
            "total_price": "0.00"
        },
        "Department C": {
            "code": "ABC001",
            "department": "Department C",
            "total_quantity": 1,
            "total_price": "100.00"
        }
    },
```

The code above missing one set of data which is incorrect.

Comment: Laravel’s Relationship is the perfect candidate for this job. It will allow you to query the same like `Sale_item::with('department')->get()`

Comment: "The `keyBy` method keys the collection by the given key. If multiple items have the same key, only the last one will appear in the new collection" https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-keyby

Comment: @miken32 Is there any other way to make it include all data instead of get last one only?

Comment: @MohamedMufeed i see. I will try the method.

Comment: What you're asking makes no sense. How could it possibly key by that value *and* keep all the elements?

Comment: @BebekimLim You should properly setup the relationship methods and relationship to be able to use that method. See <https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships>

Comment: instead of `keyBy` use `groupBy` it will group for the same department, for department A as it has two values you will get array of collection object, for department C, you will get a single collection object